# We choose $3$ cards from the standard deck of $32$ cards. What is a probabilty that we choose a spade and a diamond and an ace?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> We choose $3$ cards from the standard deck of $32$ cards. What is a probabilty that we choose a spade and a diamond and an ace?

Say this deck contains all suits from 7 up.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
&\spadesuit& \color{\red}{\diamondsuit} &  \#  \\
\hline
ace & 0 & 0 & 7\cdot 7\cdot 2=98\\
ace & 0 & 1 & 7\cdot 23 +{7\choose 2}=182\\
ace & 1 & 0 & 7\cdot 23 +{7\choose 2}=182\\
ace & 1 & 1 & 30\\
\end{array}$$

So the answer is $$P={492\over 32\cdot 31\cdot 5}={123\over 1240}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The answer clearly depends on the makeup of the $32$ card deck.

Comment: Still now? @lulu

Comment: Of course.  If the $32$ cards contain no spades, then the answer is $0$, to mention just one possibility.  There is no "standard" $32$ card deck that I am aware of.  Did you mean $52$?

Comment: Does not the standard deck contains spades? No I meant 32

Comment: To clarify, $32$ is not standard.  A **standard** card deck contains $52$ cards.

Comment: The standard deck contains 52 cards.

Comment: Ok, all suits from 7 up.

Comment: So, then the first case you consider is where the ace is neither $\spadesuit$ not $\diamondsuit$.  I agree with that computation.  I guess the second case is meant to be $A\diamondsuit$, spade other than an ace, then...what should the third card be?

Comment: You should include you reasoning for these magic numbers.  It is hard to decipher what you are counting.

Comment: Ah.  It's an ace of diamonds, *and either* one non-ace spade and one from the remaining non-spade cards **or** two non-ace spades.$$\binom 11\binom 71\binom{8+8+7}1+\binom 11\binom 72$$

Comment: @lulu: These comments are quite culture-centric :-) In Germany, a standard deck of cards has $32$ cards. I agree that this should have been explained in the post; but that's no reason to claim that standards outside the English-speaking world are somehow less standard than inside it.

Comment: @joriki  I never knew that!  What games are played with this $32$ card deck?

Comment: @joriki  Ah, so that's what a Piquet deck is. I've heard the term but never looked up the meaning.  Thanks!  I withdraw my comments.

Comment: @lulu: Interesting, I'd never heard of the game of Piquet or a Piquet deck. The game of [Skat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skat_(card_game)), the most popular card game in Germany, is played with a $32$-card deck.

Comment: @joriki  And I have never heard of Skat.  I'll look it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to count selections of a spade a diamond and an ace.

You may select

- a non-ace spade, and a non-ace diamond, and an ace of spades or clubs.
- an ace of diamonds, and either two non-ace spades or one non-ace spade and one from the remaining non-spade cards.
- an ace of spades, and either two non-ace diamonds or one non-ace diamond and one of the remaining non-diamond cards
- an ace of spades, an ace of diamonds, and one from the remaining 30 cards.

Your calculations for these are okay.  (Although it was a bit hard to decipher your table.)  But that sums to $98+182+182+30=492$

---

And, there are $\binom {32}3$ ways to select any 3 from 32 cards.   That is $4\,960$.  So$$\dfrac{492}{4\,960}=\dfrac{123}{1240}$$